# Why is dinitrogen tetroxide a planar molecule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure

[image]

I was wondering why $\ce{N2O4}$ is a planar species in spite of having a σ-bond in between the two $\ce{N}$ atoms for free rotation. Does it not form a conformer?

[image]

Comment: Because pi conjugation.

Comment: Why there would be delocalisation of pi electron cloud over N-N bond   as the RS formed would be highly unstable as it would have + charge on oxygen atom with  high electron deficiency

Comment: No, it wouldn't have + on oxygen.

Comment: The oxygen with the -charge is  in conjugation only with the oxygen present in the same N atom .It can't be in conjugation with the =O present in the other N atom . How there can be partial bond between 2 N atoms

Comment: Well, just like that. Each O with minus. Each N with plus. Double bond between N.

Comment: I have added the diagrams of RS

Comment: Good. Now see, there is one more resonance structure.

Comment: I think it is a very good question (why the down vote?) - by comparison the geometry that the isoelectronic oxalate ion adopts in crystals depends upon the counter cation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalate) indicating that in that case at least the energy well keeping the ion planar is not that deep - so why is N2O4 planar? pi conjugation would suggest double bond character in the N-N bond, but as is well known that bond is weak and long, so I don't find that a very satisfying explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that one would expect that a stable form of the molecule might be planar and have **D2h** symmetry.

Some support for the claim:

1. Early crystal structures suggested that the ONO bonds on either side
   of the N-N bond are easily modeled by low level DFT
   (doi.org/10.1039/C19660000082).
2. More recently, simulations of the trans and cis N2O4 structure show
   planarity when optimized at B3LYP/ aug-cc-pVTZ (aka, pretty good not
   amazing) [See here](https://acdc.amherst.edu/view/octagon:153/CONTENT).

The simulations also suggest that the barrier to isomerization is low, meaning that while the stable structures are planar, there are low barrier (low temperature) out of plane rotations possible.

**Summary**:

1. Just because something has sigma bonds doesn't imply that it will immediately be non-planar
2. *yes* the molecule can form a conformer